# Deploying using Rinkeby understanding

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, rinkeby

Deploy we are using  truffle

> truffle migrate --reset --compile-all --network rinkeby

when i am deploying i will be getting **build** folder in my project directory  while deploying through  the rinkeby will it  take the build folder  and  deploy. or what file we are deploying  in the solidity using these command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `migrate` command of truffle will run the scripts in your migrations directory. See the documentation https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations in truffle site.

The `--reset` option will force to redeploy all your contracts.

The `--compile-all` will force recompilation of all your contracts.

Comment: what is the use of build directory in your project

Comment: Truffle uses the build directory to store compilation artifacts, bytecode, abi, deployment address, etc.